# How should i handle my redis connections inside celery Tasks?

Tags: redis, celery

I have a celery server that handles some counters for my application

```
class IncrementStatsCounterTask(Task):
    def run(self, count, shortcode, stat_type, operator_id, date,  **kwargs):
        r_server = redis.Redis(settings.REDIS_HOST)
        key = key_mask % {
            'shortcode': shortcode,
            'stat_type': stat_type,
            'operator_id': operator_id,
            'date': date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        }

        return key, r_server.incr(key, count)
```

It all works great,however this opens and closes the redis connection every time my task, runs. Is there a better way to handle the connections? maybe have some sort of persistent connection?

I'm running latest django-celery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [python redis library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/) you can use connection pooling. Just create a pool globally in one of your modules and use it for every new connection.

Comment: Don't think so. But it will be shared across all tasks in a worker.

Comment: This answer should have a code snipped to how to achieve this. How do define this globally in a module?